# VS 2008 Custom Action during Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-xp, custom-action

My issue is the following: I need to run a .bat and a .exe file during installation. I wrote a .bat that runs them sequentially with the WAIT command, so that I would only have to run 1 file during my installation. I created a Custom Action, and ran the .bat file just like it says in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414956/how-to-run-a-bat-file-during-installation) question, and it works on windows 7. However, I need it to work on XP since that is the OS which my application will be deployed on. When I try to install on XP, I get the following error message:

"There is a problem with the windows install package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."

I looked at many sources online, and tried lots of solutions, but nothing works.

I tried deleting the contents of my %temp% folder, but it didn't help. I am using Administrator, so I don't think privileges are the issue. I don't know what to do, and I need this to work...can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXE custom actions show this error when their return value is not 0. So make sure that your BAT file doesn't return a non-zero value. Also, check if your command line works correctly on older Windows versions.