# Run a batch file during installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I want to run a batch file – say `driver.bat` – after the application installation is completed. This has to be done using the Visual Studio setup and deployment while creating package. [This question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414956/how-to-run-a-bat-file-during-installation), but the solution is giving me a problem: once the installation is done, it’s throwing an error message like:

> 'cmd.exe' should be excluded because its source file is under Windows File Protection

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when the file is marked as a protected file on the Windows operating system. You need to exclude the file from this protection to execute successfully. The following link would help you do so -

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x97ae5d9(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x97ae5d9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)