# Grant permissions on MSI installation

Tags: c#, permissions, installation

I have a problem with the deployment of my app:
I created the app in C# (Windows Forms) on Windows 7, tested it, working just fine. I moved the .exe and dlls to another computer with Windows 10, tested, working just fine. All good with the app until now.
The next step is to create a setup file for it. I managed to create the setup file, it installs my app, the app work but can't create files (log files for example - files are stored next to .exe file). I found out that the folder needs full control permissions for Users. How can I set the permissions to the folder when the app is installing?

Comment: Try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2294cb5-5d8a-4275-9651-b0a2933fccc1/create-a-folder-with-permissions-set-to-this-folder-subfolders?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I tried to set permissions to the folder in Program Files on app startup. Not working. In that link is basically the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not as elegant as I wanted but it works: on commit, the setup will execute a .bat file with a script that will give full permissions for IIS_IUSER.

Check this link:
[How to run a ".bat" file during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414956/how-to-run-a-bat-file-during-installation)